# Joinin multiple tables with double group by,double count

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to expand my Select to handle displaying number of files associated with Unique "NR_REKLAMACJI". I Got table 'rtransportowa' where i keep all details, 'klienci' where i get Name and Surname and now im trying to join table 'pliki' or 'files' as well, to keep track on how many files there are for corresponding 'NR_REKLAMACJI'.

Tried adding Count(files.FileName) on select and then Inner joining it and  using group by NR_REKLAMACJI, files.NR_REK

```
SELECT
  `NR_REKLAMACJI`,
  COUNT(NR_REKLAMACJI) AS 'ilosc reklamowanego towaru',
  CONCAT(klienci.IMIE, ' ', klienci.NAZWISKO) AS 'Klient',
  CONCAT(users.IMIE, ' ', users.NAZWISKO) AS 'Osoba zajmująca się',
  DOK_FV,
  klienci.NAZWA_FIRMY,
  DATA

FROM
  `rtransportowa`
  INNER JOIN klienci ON ID_R = klienci.ID_KLIENTA
  INNER JOIN users ON ID_U = users.ID_USER

group by
  NR_REKLAMACJI
```

My goal is to group table 'rtransportowa' to show unique 'NR_REKLAMACJI" and count number of "NR_REKLAMACJI" from rtransportowa and files,

I got TABLE1 with not unique field NAME, TABLE 2 having also field NAME, and i want to group it by showing all things from TABLE1 + Count(NAME), grouping it by field NAME, and for this add Count of (TABLE2.NAME) also grouped by the TABLE1.NAME

```
+------+-------------+--------------------+
| Name | Count(Name) | Count(TABLE2.Name) |
+------+-------------+--------------------+
| aaa  |           2 |                  3 |
| bbb  |           3 |                  0 |
| ccc  |           1 |                 45 |
+------+-------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].